# 文字列から数値を抽出し、合計したい

Tags: python

「国語20数学30」から20+30=50を求めたい。データには、このペアが1000件ほど存在します。
re.matchを使えると思うのですが、どうもうまく行きません。ヒントをご教示頂けるとありがたいです。

reを使わないバージョンですが、現在のところ、下記のように書いているのですが、
うまく行きません。

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['国語20数学60', '160', '国語100数学20']},
    index=[1, 2, 3])

# index no.2には、国語と数学の合計点が入っています。 

print(df)

df['total'] = np.zeros((len(df),1))  
lang = list(range(1, 101))  
math  =list(range(1, 101))  
for s_lang in lang :
    for s_math in math :
        for i in range(len(df)):
            if ("国語%d数学%d" %(s_lang,s_math)) in df['x'][i]:   
              df['total'][i] = s_lang+s_math
            else:
                df['total'][i] =df['x'][i] 

print(df)
```

Comment: ご自分ではどのようなコードを書いてそれではどのように「うまく行かない」のか質問に追記してください

Comment: pandas の dataframe に適用するのあれば、例えば、`df['total'] = df.apply(lambda i: sum(map(int, filter(None, re.split(r'[^0-9]', i.x)))), axis=1)` などでしょうか(事前に `import re` を実行)。少なくとも、掲示されているデータ(df)に対しては期待される結果が得られます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。lambda関数の使い方を学ぶことができました。大変勉強になります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

正規表現で数値(の文字列)を抽出し、それをint関数で数値に変えて加算すればよいのではないでしょうか。

正規表現で数値(の文字列)を抽出の部分は、以下のような感じ

```
#正規表現のモジュールをインポートしておく
import re

#数値にマッチするパターン（0～9の文字(数字)の繰り返し)を定義
pattern=r'([0-9]*)'

#元の文字列が変数textに入っているものとすると、re.findallを使ってlistsに数値を表す文字列のリストが得られる
lists=re.findall(pattern,text)
```

textの内容が'国語20数学30'だとすると、lists=['20','30']となるはず。

文字列を数値に変えて加算する部分は簡単だと思うので省略。

Answer (score 0):

pythonは「int」関数で文字列を10進数の整数に変換する事ができます。

また、そのような文字列では[数値の抽出にre.matchを使えません](https://qiita.com/wrblue_mica34/items/9253d6ba7e0baf5cc714)。

Answer (score -2):

pythonを使わない方法なら、

方法1.エクセルで正規表現を使う。 
(参考)Excelのワークシート関数で正規表現を使う 
https://qiita.com/ktyubeshi/items/74228f18498224c7427d
A1を国語20数学30
B1を=RegExp(A1,"(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)(\d+)",2-1)+RegExp(A1,"(\D+)(\d+)(\D+)(\d+)",4-1)

方法2.エクセルの関数を使う。 
.(参考)エクセルで特定の文字の前までを取り出す、特定の文字以降を取り出す 
https://qiita.com/yuwaita/items/b7445bcc7b09c143fcf7
A1を国語20数学30 
B1を=MID(LEFT(A1,FIND("数学",A1)-1),3,LEN(A1))+MID(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-(FIND("数学",A1)-1)),3,LEN(A1))

方法3,"数学"と"国語"を","に置き換え後、csvファイルにする。("数学"と"国語"を"数学,"と"国語,"に置換して、csvファイルにする。) 
csvファイルをエクセルで読む。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Excelでのやり方も勉強になります。